# Is $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I want to know if the gaussian integers are a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module. Obviously, they are if you use the definition from wikipedia where you just have to find a base - which would be $\{1,i\}$ for $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.

But I have to use following definition:

A $R$-module $F$ is called free if $\exists$ function $I\rightarrow F$ ($I$ is some index set) and a $R$-module isomorphism $R^{(I)}:=\bigoplus_{i\in I} R \rightarrow F$ so that this diagram is commutative:

[image]

Definition for iota: $\iota_i:R_i \rightarrow\bigoplus_k R_k, \quad x\mapsto (x_i)_i$

Definition for $\bigoplus$: $\bigoplus_i R_i = \{(x_i)_i \in \prod_i R_i: x_i\neq 0 \text{ for at most finite $i$'s}\}$

---

My attempt:

I thought about taking $I=\mathbb{N}$. Then we have $\iota_1(1)=(1,0,0,0,...)$, $\iota_2(1)=(0,1,0,0,...)$, ..., $\in \mathbb{Z}^{(I)}$

Define...
$$\varphi: \mathbb{Z}^{(I)}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}[I],\quad \iota_j(1) \mapsto \begin{cases}  1 & \text{if $j \mod 4 \equiv 0$} \\ -1 & \text{if $j \mod 4 \equiv 1$} \\ i & \text{if $j \mod 4 \equiv 2$} \\ -i & \text{if $j \mod 4 \equiv 3$} \end{cases}$$

I think this should be an isomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}^{(I)}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}[I]$. It's definitely a homomorphism.

Did I miss something?

Comment: Hint: $|I|=2.{}{}{}$ The images of the $I$ are the generators.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews So you mean $(1,0),(0,1)\in\mathbb{Z}^{(2)}$ and then $(1,0)\mapsto 1$, $(0,1)\mapsto i$ ?

Comment: An overkill way to see this is [the structure theorem for finitely generated abelian groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely_generated_abelian_group#Classification). This view is nice since it generalizes well to arbitrary rings of integers in number fields.